# How to log what the Oracle system user is doing?

Tags: oracle, logging

I'm trying to install BMC Remedy Action Request System 9.1.04 with Oracle 12. The installer says `Unable to create Dummy User with provided password` but the geniuses from BMC wouldn't tell you in any of the logs what they're trying to do at this stage. At this stage the installer is using the Oracle system user which works perfectly fine in sqlplus.

Can someone tell me how to log the activity of the system user to find out what exactly that installer cannot do?

Comment: Have your DBAs defined a password policy for your database and does the password you put in conform to both your password policy and the default? ref: https://communities.bmc.com/thread/174044?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: No password policy. I'm using standard password as I've been doing for the past 20 years or so. So from your comment I assume there is no way to enable logging in Oracle that would allow me to see that user is trying to achieve, right?

Comment: If you haven't paid for fine-grained auditing then as far as I'm aware you're down to [capturing data from V$SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11414216/458741) and adding a DDL trigger. Personally, I'd look at the alert log find the trace files and see if I could work if out. If there's an executable you're running (and so you can't see what's happening) I'd contact the vendors and ask them to debug as a series of statements without knowledge of the intention behind them probably won't be that helpful.

Comment: Look this DB is user only by one user: system. I know very little about how oracle works but I'm sure there must be a way to display what sql statements that system user is issuing. BMC support is so bad that I'm not going to waste my weeks playin email ping pong with those guys trying to explain to them what needs to me done. I've be for over 20 years in this business and it's getting worse and worse.

Comment: I've already linked you to a good write up on what's possible, and the compromises you're going to have to make, without giving Oracle more money. It may well be worthwhile raising something with BMC support now anyway, just in case.

Comment: There are ways to log the user actions, however I assume Oracle is so "smart" that it will mask any passwords automatically. For sure a DDL trigger based on `ALTER USER ...` does not show the password in clear text, i.e. in `sql_txt()` the password is replaced by `*******`